# Split a column based on a different delimiter and apply a condition

Tags: awk, csv

I'm filtering the following table:

```
1   12907284    EXON    0.4337370362636598|0.3641439953194638
1   22329062    INTRON  0.49293080505655357|0.49301629531094115
1   22332332    INTRON  0.016239257239498844|0.016134012660182183
1   24201919    EXON    0.6183022425084342|0.6181532611391254
```

The idea would be to split column `$4` by the delimiter `|`, take the first sub-string and check a condition, if it's true it'd print the entire table. For this I'm applying this `awk` command, but something is wrong because it's not working properly:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} split($4, a, "\\|"); a[1] < 0.01 {print}' file.tsv
```

Any suggestion/correction, please? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this was only a typo, I've already edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample Input_file doesn't look to have TAB delimited so I am making it as `[[:space]]+`, in case your actual Input_file is TAB delimited then you could change `-F` value to `\t` too.

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+' '{split($4,array,"|");if(array[1]<0.01){print}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Do you even need `-F` here? Splitting on blanks should be the default behaviour, no?

Comment: The 3rd arg for split() is a regexp, not a string, so use regexp, not string, delimiters. Also a `|` as the first char in a regexp is undefined behavior per POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

If your input doesn't accept `|` anywhere else than in your example, you could use a regular expression as field separator to parse the two different parts of your current 4th field as two different fields :

```
awk -F'[\t|]' '$4 < 0.1 { print }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{split($4,a,/\|/)} a[1] < 0.01' file.tsv
```